# How did Celine Dion become so good in English although she's not a native English speaker?

Tags: history, pop, language

Celine Dion is born in Charlemagne, Quebec, Canada. Quebec is mainly a French province since most people speak French, yet we see that Celine Dion is perfect in English even though also her first Albums were in French. How did she become so good in English?

Searching such a question on Google gives too many results, I want to know the actual true answer. I think this is on-topic here. Also, I think the tags aren't perfect, feel free to correct them!

Comment: Most children growing in a country where two or more languages are spoken become fluent with all of them, I think.

Comment: @MarcLeBihan Hey Marc, feel free to write an answer. This site is pretty inactive, I'll just wait until a cool person writes an answer :-)

Comment: Only she and those close to her can know for sure, and the chance one of them, or Celine herself, will post here is... well... pretty low. So we can only guess. My best guess is a private tutor, it costs a lot, but she has a lot to spare and it's probably the best and fastest way to learn. Since it's just a guess, it doesn't fit as answer on SE sites, so sadly you'll probably be left without official answer here.